# Python - Remove Hidden Characters From Dataframe Column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a dataframe that when I export the data to a csv I am getting some weird results.

Here would be a sample of it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['Dates'] = ['Day 1', '10pm', 'Day 2', '7pm', 'Day 3', '6pm']
df['Data'] = ['7½o-20', '-278/+222', '8o-15', '-109/-101', '8½u-15', '-195/+162']
```

Now having this data, I export it to a csv but the 'Data' values change/add characters. I do not see these characters within my code editor, but may be possible that they are hidden characters?

So the column in the csv would look like this:

| Dates | Data |
| --- | --- |
| Day 1 | 7Â½o-20 |
| 10pm | -1.15225 |
| Day 2 | 8o-15 |
| 7pm | 1.079208 |
| Day 3 | 8Â½u-15 |
| 6 pm | -1.2037 |

So for the data values that contain the ½, excel is adding a Â symbol in front of the ½.
And then for the data with the forward slash, excel is adding an equal sign and then treating the data like an equation.

I am not sure why this is happening, but I would like the data to show just as it does in my code editor.

Comment: I am unable to replicate your issue using the sample data and `df.to_csv()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap you the `Data` column with `=""` to prevent excel from treating it as an equation. What this does is tell excel to treat the entry as a formula that returns the text within quotes. The code looks like this:

```
df.Data = df.Data.apply('="{}"'.format)
```

You can use `utf-8-sig` encoding when using the `to_csv()` method to fix the `Â` issue:

```
df.to_csv('file.csv',encoding='utf-8-sig', index=False)
```

These are the contents of `file.csv` after the changes:

| Dates | Data |
| --- | --- |
| Day 1 | 7½o-20 |
| 10pm | -278/+222 |
| Day 2 | 8o-15 |
| 7pm | -109/-101 |
| Day 3 | 8½u-15 |
| 6pm | -195/+162 |

Comment: So that did resolve getting rid of the Â symbol, but I am also trying to prevent excel from adding the equal symbol. So I am wanting to still output "-278/+222" rather than "-1.25225" which excel is doing "=-278/222".

Comment: Hey @Link, I've added additional code to address the second issue.